# Back-propagation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am constructing a time delayed recurrent model and I need to know about how and when TensorFlow computes its backwards step.

Consider the following model and pseudo-code:

[image: A time-delayed recurrent network]

```
unit_1 = LSTM(unit_size)
unit_2 = LSTM(unit_size)
unit_3 = LSTM(unit_size)
unit_4 = LSTM(unit_size)

ip_W = Variable([4 * unit_size, output_size])
ip_b = Variable([output_size])

prev_1 = tf.zeros([unit_size])
prev_2 = tf.zeros([unit_size])
prev_3 = tf.zeros([unit_size])
prev_4 = tf.zeros([unit_size])

for t, input in enumerate(input_data):
    if t%1==0:
        prev_1 = unit_1([input])
    if t%2==0:
        prev_2 = unit_2([input])
    if t%3==0:
        prev_3 = unit_3([input])
    if t%4==0:
        prev_4 = unit_4([input])

    concat = tf.concat(0,[prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4])
    output[t] = tf.matmul(concat, ip_W) + ip_B
```

[Here is a gist to a usable version of this code, based on tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py](https://gist.github.com/aidangomez/7657ff6c053d0ccc2f4d)

## My Question:

For time steps where cells are not called (i.e. at T=1, unit_0 is called, while all the rest are not) are their weights updated? I'm torn as to whether it would be a good idea to have them update at every state or not. The cells themselves haven't been exposed to any new data in the steps, so I afraid that back propagating may result in over-correction. Would appreciate other's insights into this.

Let me know if any clarification is necessary.